# Storable instance of Maybe

Tags: haskell, ffi

I'm trying to find an instance of `Foreign.Storable` for `Maybe`. Google turned up an instance from [C2HS](https://github.com/haskell/c2hs/blob/master/C2HS.hs)

```
instance Storable a => Storable (Maybe a) where
  sizeOf    _ = sizeOf    (undefined :: Ptr ())
  alignment _ = alignment (undefined :: Ptr ())

  peek p = do
             ptr <- peek (castPtr p)
             if ptr == nullPtr
               then return Nothing
               else liftM Just $ peek ptr

  poke p v = do
               ptr <- case v of
                        Nothing -> return nullPtr
                        Just v' -> new v'
               poke (castPtr p) ptr
```

but also [a post](http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/Storable-Maybe-a-leaks-memory-td3196620.html) about how it leaks memory. Is there an existing instance somewhere else, or a way to improve the C2HS instance? Why isn't there an instance in `Foreign.Storable` to begin with?

Comment: If you're ok with treating `Nothing` as exactly equivalent to `nullPtr`, you can easily write this without leaking.  Otherwise, I don't see a way to write this without doing some manual memory management (or losing polymorphism).

Comment: @JohnL That seems reasonable to me. Why would I not want to do that? I'm not actually calling C with any `Maybe` values, it's all temporary stuff in Haskell only.

Comment: Hmm, I think I was mistaken, that approach doesn't seem as easy as I expected.  I do think I have an approach that works, but why do you need a `Storable` for temporary data in Haskell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a potential instance, [available on School of Haskell](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/snoyberg/random-code-snippets/storable-instance-of-maybe). The idea is to store an extra byte containing either a 0 or 1, indicating whether the value exists or not.

There are certainly more efficient approaches for individual `Storable` instance. For example, a `Maybe Bool` could be stored in a single byte instead of two bytes. But I don't think you can avoid the 1-byte overhead in the general case.

Here's the main part of my solution:

```
instance Storable a => Storable (Maybe a) where
    sizeOf x = sizeOf (stripMaybe x) + 1
    alignment x = alignment (stripMaybe x)
    peek ptr = do
        filled <- peekByteOff ptr $ sizeOf $ stripMaybe $ stripPtr ptr
        if filled == (1 :: Word8)
            then do
                x <- peek $ stripMaybePtr ptr
                return $ Just x
            else return Nothing
    poke ptr Nothing = pokeByteOff ptr (sizeOf $ stripMaybe $ stripPtr ptr) (0 :: Word8)
    poke ptr (Just a) = do
        poke (stripMaybePtr ptr) a
        pokeByteOff ptr (sizeOf a) (1 :: Word8)
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is better than the C2HS instance?

Comment: The C2HS instance stores a pointer to the data you need, so you have a lever of indirection and extra memory overhead for the pointer (a full machine word). This approach avoids the extra indirection, keeps all the data in the same area in memory, and instead of an extra machine word per element, you have an extra byte per element.